# Fixed position navbar slideUp slideDown function breaks after scrolling down

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slideup

I recently implemented a position fixed navbar on my website which is accessed by clicking the menu button in the top left corner of the site. It works fine at the top of the page, but after scrolling up or down, the slideUp / slideDown function glitches. It works well in Safari and on the Chrome browser on my phone, but breaks in Firefox and Chrome on a desktop.

The site is at: http://zackfischmann.com

All of the code can be found at https://github.com/zfisch/zfisch.github.io, but I included the most relevant code below as well.

JS:

```
$('#menu').click(function(){
    var nav = $('#navbar').css("display");
    var item = $('#navbar').css("display");
    if (nav == 'none') {        
        $("#navbar").slideDown();
        }
    else {
        $("#navbar").slideUp();
    }
    if (item == 'none') {
        $("#navbar-items").slideDown();
    }
    else {
        $("#navbar-items").slideUp();
    }});
```

HTML for the navbar:

```
<div id="menu">
        <a href="#menu">
            <img src="img/menu.svg" alt="" height="40px" width="40px">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar">  
        <div class="row" id="navbar-items">
            <div class="navbar-link col-xs-3">
                <a class="scroll" href="#Home"><span>Home</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-link col-xs-3">
                <a class="scroll" href="#About"><span>About</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-link col-xs-3">
                <a class="scroll" href="#Projects"><span>Projects</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-link col-xs-3">
                <a class="scroll" href="#Contact"><span>Contact</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
float: left;
z-index: 1900000;
position: fixed;
}

#navbar {
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0.6;
background-color: black;
position: fixed;
z-index: 10;
display:none;
}

.navbar-link {
font-size: 1.5em;
list-style-type: none;
color: #fff;
font-weight: 300;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 5px
}

#navbar-items {
display: none;
text-align: center
}

#navbar-items a:link {
text-decoration:none;
color: #fff;
}

#navbar-items a:visited {
text-decoration:none;
color: #fff;
}

#navbar-items a:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
color: #fff;
}

#navbar-items a:active {
text-decoration:none;
color: #fff;
}
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!!

---

## Update

I decided to remove the navbar for aesthetic reasons, but am leaving this question up in case it's relevant for future builders.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would suggest the default for the menu to be shown in desktop screen size.  You don't even notice the icon up there with the full screen picture taking all the attention then once you start scrolling you can't see it at all over the white background. so if you didn't see it before you start scrolling, you will never know there is a menu.
You have some flickering going on there while scrolling.  I've noticed this type of behavior when there are syntax errors in the code.  I can see 2 up there in your css. `#navbar-items` and `.navbar-link` are both missing closing ;
Make sure there are no errors like that in your css, html, and most importantly your js

Comment: Semicolons are not required in the last line of css code, but thanks for design feedback.

Comment: i'm just sayin'...if you've left them out there, you may have left them out elsewhere.